# How do I get these text input boxes to line up?

Tags: html, css

How do I get the text input boxes to line up?

The password input box is slightly to the left, it is not aligned with the username text input box.

I am using Java, in Eclipse.

```html
<div>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </div>
  <form name="loginform">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Login Form</legend>
      <label>Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" /><span>*</span>
      </label>
      <label>Password:
        <input type="password" name="pass" /><span>*</span>
      </label>
      <input type="reset" class="resetButton" />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submitButton" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: the simple answer would be to create a `<table>` for your input fields and labels.

Comment: No, tables should not be used here.

Comment: uuuuh, yeah, they should.... use a table

Comment: Tables are for tabular data. If something is not aligning correctly, it is a CSS issue.

Comment: tables are not needed "at all", see my answer for easy fix

Comment: they aren't needed but there is onthing wrong with using them. tonnes of sites still use tables to structure a layout. https://jsfiddle.net/nftcdbh9/

Comment: @Pamblam There is something wrong with using them. It's an old-school makeshift way to align something that is simply not needed any more, and becomes problematic for other designers & developers.

Comment: no, they've been used for years. your opinion is not gospel truth. i know that's what they're teaching in schools these days, but that still doesn't make it gospel truth. if a table causes problems for you as a developer maybe you should consider another career..

Comment: I'll give a simple, common sense reason why Tables aren't a great idea -- responsiveness.  Tables just aren't responsive, and they'll suffer immensely in layout as the browser changes size or the screen is compressed like on a mobile device.  Sure, quick and dirty they work, and they'll scale some.  But you completely lose control of wrapping at some point.  Some point at your career, you'll have to deal with an overzealous UX pro getting a hold of your work, and trust me, it won't be pretty if you're laying out with tables.....

Comment: @Pamblam It's up to you if you want to give out-of-date advice, but if the OP would like his site to be responsive any time soon, he will find your table suggestion a bad idea, and won't thank you for it.

Comment: @bpeterson76 Can't agree with you more, if one use `table` for general layout. My answer though, take advantage of the `display` property and can easily, using media queries, switch between `table`, `flex` and `block` and become as responsive as one want, so if I assume you down voted my answer, I think it does not deserve that.

Comment: Rbo111 do you have any thoughts of your own? You keep agreeing with and reiterating points others have made but i dont see you posting any answers or sample code.. im not disagreeing that pure css is a better solution but the answer below as is, is not responsive either. A table can be made responsive just as easily as a css method with media queries. Sorry, but responsiveness is not the issue here, the issue is you are discrediting a perfectly valid method just because there is a way to do it with a little less markup.

Comment: If two methods achieve the same result then its not a Ux issue. The ux is exactly the same either way.

Comment: @Pamblam Please don't be surprised if I concur with good advice. Tables are not simple to make responsive, and if you don't believe me, try making your layout responsive on your own jsfiddle link. Also, would you rather I add a similar answer to the one I agree with? Because that's not how this site works.

Comment: Its not a matter of good advice. Op got his his answer and i think everyone agrees that peterson gave the best answer. Its not personal im standing on principal.

Comment: @Pamblam Alright then. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be dynamic, you need a grid (row/column) structure, and the best one (cross browser) today is `display: table`, as `display: grid` is still widely unsupported ([working draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#grid-containers) | [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid))

```css
h1 {letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: .4in; color: green;}

legend {font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold}

fieldset{width: 300px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color : limegreen}

label {display: block; position: relative; line-height: 2;}

.text {position: absolute; margin-left: 20px; width: 15em; left: 80px}

.grid {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.col {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 6px 0 0 6px;
}
.col.after:after {
  content: ' *';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </div>
  <form name="loginform">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Login Form</legend>

      <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col after">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="pass">Password:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col after">
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="reset" class ="resetButton"/> 
            <input type="submit" value = "Login" class="submitButton"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: W3 says that labels are elements -- not wrappers.  They shouldn't be used to encapsulate another element, they should stand alone and utilize the "for" tag to tie them to the element they describe.  Divs and Spans are containers, but in this case to simply set a width on the label you'd apply it to the label, not do summersaults to avoid it.

Comment: @bpeterson76 Just updated my answer ... so if you down voted you might want to undo that now

Comment: It's still using redundant markup, even with the changes.  There's no reason to add a div with a width when you could simply size and position the label.

Comment: @bpeterson76 Since `flex` can't act as a grid in all cases, which my answer suggests to use, that can't be solved with just position the label.

Comment: @bpeterson76 Seeing as [the standard uses a label wrapping a textfield input as an example for the `label` tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element), mind telling me where in the standards/spec it says you shouldn't wrap for linking a label to an input?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the username and password labels in an `inline-block` `span` and give that `span` a `width`.

Your updated html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style tpye ="text/css">
        h1 {letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: .4in; color: green;}
        span {color: red}
        legend {font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold}
        fieldset{width: 300px; font-family: Arial; sans-serif;
                 background-color : limegreen}
        label {display: block; position relative; line-height: 2;
                margin: 10px 0px;}
        .text {position: absolute; margin-left: 20px; width: 15em; left: 80px}
        span.myspan{width: 100px; display:inline-block;}
    </style>
    <div>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
            <form name="loginform">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login Form</legend>
                <label><span class="myspan">Username:</span> <input type="text" name="username"/><span>*</span></label>
                <label><span class="myspan">Password:</span> <input type="password" name="pass"/><span>*</span></label>
                <input type="reset" class ="resetButton"/> 
                <input type="submit" value = "Login" class="submitButton"/>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Test here: https://jsfiddle.net/nabtron/d4cr66oa/

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect W3 standard world, your label would be a field that stands on its own, not a field that encapsulates the input.  So, for instance:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label> 
<input id="username" type="text" name="username"/><span>*</span>
```

The "for" tag refers to the ID of the input field that you'd have to add.  Styling, then would be as simple as adding on a width to the style of the label.  For positioning purposes, you could display-inline on the required asterisk to position it after the input.

Comment: @rybo111 Seeing as [the standard uses a label wrapping a textfield input as an example for the `label` tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element), mind telling me where in the standards/spec it says you should only wrap checkboxen and radio buttons?

Comment: @abluejelly fair point; I've removed my comment. I still agree with this answer, though, as it is a common, accepted approach.

Comment: @rybo111 tbh it's a very clunky approach, as it pollutes your ID space with IDs that exist for potentially no reason (as well as unnecessary locs). You should only use the `for` attribute if it is needed (cannot wrap for other reasons), not simply because you can. And from a maintainability standpoint, the only boon from always using the `for` is the ID space was likely initially conceived with the ID pre-reserved. However, it adds another ID to what you need to check for before adding a new ID, resulting in a zero net gain.

Comment: @abluejelly I see your point regarding unnecessary IDs. I think the term "label" confuses matters. Bootstrap have [helped popularise the use of `label` separately](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), and now they [appear to endorse `fieldset` and `label` for one text input](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#form-controls) in their v4 docs, whereas using `label` implicitly would suffice.

Comment: @abluejelly Please can you share an example that uses `<label>` as a wrapper in the way you have described? Specifically, I'm keen to see how you display errors and handle responsive design using this technique in a real-world example.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked, thank you.

```css
h1 {letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: .4in; color: green;}

legend {font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold}

fieldset{width: 300px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color : limegreen}

label {display: block; position: relative; line-height: 2;}

.text {position: absolute; margin-left: 20px; width: 15em; left: 80px}

.grid {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.col {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 6px 0 0 6px;
}
.col.after:after {
  content: ' *';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </div>
  <form name="loginform">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Login Form</legend>

      <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col after">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="pass">Password:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col after">
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="reset" class ="resetButton"/> 
            <input type="submit" value = "Login" class="submitButton"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If something worked, you just need to accept the answer. No need to add another answer.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. According to SO policy, you aren't suppose to repost the accepted answer as your chosen one, that's what the accept is for, so please delete it to avoid confusion for future readers.